# Street View error

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm running into an issue the last couple of days on my website. When trying to switch to Street View on a map - after dropping the yellow man on a street - I get a grey screen (see screen grab).
My console (on Chrome) shows this error, which pops up when doing the switch:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: Map
>       at defineProperty ()
>       at pa (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/30/5/intl/en_gb/imagery_viewer.js:3:229)
>       at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/30/5/intl/en_gb/imagery_viewer.js:7:1
>       at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/30/5/intl/en_gb/imagery_viewer.js:866:268

I had this problem in the past too, but I solved it by downgrading my google maps version. 
My init_map:

```
function init_map() {
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.632909,17.138672),
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        gestureHandling: 'greedy',
        mapStreetViewControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
        },      
        overviewMapControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), myOptions);
```

I was working with the 3.29 and it was working fine, now, I have problems with Version 3.31:

```
<script src="maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.31&key=....."; type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: post some code?

Comment: how do you load the maps libraries? Can you post the code?

Comment: <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.31&key=....." type="text/javascript"></script> //i had already tried all the versions. It works fine for me until 14.02 but only with version 3.29 who has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

We were facing the very same error string, but seen when loading just the embedded map itself. It appeared that we were redefining the function `Map()` within another one of our (now unused) JS files, renaming this function resolved the issue.

I didn't come to this conclusion entirely on my own, see [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/maps/RJzEriijkek/vEI8n40rBAAJ) for a user describing the very same issue as yourself.